# Xcode: Control drag only works in first storyboard view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

When I make a project in Xcode and choose template to Single view application, I can only just control drag the first storyboard's view controller elements to ViewController .m and .h. I understand, I chose SINGLE view application, but I think there should be another option.

I tested "Tabbed Application" and that template creates own .h and .m files for every view controller. I tested to rename `ViewController.h` and .m to `FirstViewContoller.h` and .m. It was messed now. So, I deleted the project and here I am.

What should I do?

Comment: What is it that you want to do?  That is, when you say "there should be another option", what kind of option?

Comment: I searched from Google yesterday all day, but nothing came up. Also I tried to find something relases to that in iOS Development manual, but I found nothing. Sorry for asking newbie quetions! Also I found similar questions in stack overflow, but those was never answered.

Comment: I want  to create IBOutlets and IBActions. I think 2-Stroker's answer is right, I will try after I will get back home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` in new view controllers.

When you create a new view controller in storyboard, go to Identity Inspector and set Custom Class to the new View controller. Then you can Control drag the elements to the view controller.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Just searcing Custom Class in google opened like new world! Thank REALLY MUCH!

Comment: Does this work with any type of object? I am trying to do the same thing with some `UITextField`s. I changed the class in Identity Inspector to that of the ViewController I want and it doesn't change anything. When I click on something else the class I selected is gone. Even if I press enter.

Comment: Every time I try and add a class that I know exists into the Identity Inspector it just goes away as soon as I click something else.

Comment: I even tried creating a `UITextView` class and using that as the class and still found no luck. It just goes away as soon as click anything else.

Comment: @CGTheLegend If you have to customize `UITextField` you will have to create a class which inherits from `UITextField`. If you are not sure which class you have to subclass just look at the class section.

Comment: I am just trying to get the keyboard to dismiss once I click done and or click outside of the keyboard. Do I really need a custom class for that?

Answer (score 0):

When you renamed the files did you rename the @interface and @implementation to match your new class name as well? In the header (.h file) it should say

`@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController`

and in the implementation (.m file) it should say

```
@implementation FirstViewController
```

Hope that helps